# How to bind appsettings.json to class?

Tags: c#, json, appsettings

I have an appsettings.json file in my C# app. It contains field with names in upper case:

```
{
    "FIELD_ONE": "foo",
    "FIELD_TWO": "bar"
}
```

But I would like to bind it to class with camel-case naming style:

```
public class MySettings
{
    public string FieldOne { get; set; }
    public string FieldTwo { get; set; }
}
```

How can I bind this appsettings to `MySettings` instance?

Comment: You might have to do it [manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.getvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_ConfigurationBinder_GetValue__1_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfiguration_System_String_) - `FieldOne = config.GetValue<string>("FIELD_ONE")`

Answer (score 1):

This could be a solution:

```
public class MySettings
{
     [JsonProperty("FIELD_ONE")]
     public string FieldOne { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("FIELD_TWO")]
     public string FieldTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: does not work for me

Comment: and what about this?                                                                                                            public string FIELD_ONE { get; set; }                                                                              
public string FIELD_TWO { get; set; }

Comment: it works but I would like to use camel-case in my class

Comment: I think it's impossible but I'm not sure